# Richfaces modalPanel scrolling

Tags: java, richfaces

Im using Richfaces 3.3.

I open modal panel (with scrollableDataTable inside). When I scroll up/down, I expect that scrollableDataTable in modal panel will be scrolled. But parent window is scrolled instead. How can I fix it?

Comment: Post the XHTML code with sample data to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.rich-mpnl-panel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If it is not going to be enough alone try sth. like this:

```
<rich:scrollableDataTable> 
    <div class="scrollable"/>
<rich:scrollableDataTable>
```

And apply this class:

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```